# Share photo on facebook without app

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to redirect the user to the browser to share a photo from my app if there is no facebook app installed.

I'm using:

```
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setImageUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(path))
                .build();

        final SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
           //Sharing via facebook app
            shareDialog.show(content);
        } else {
           //Sharing via browser
           Intent shareCaptionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/userxxxx"));
           shareCaptionIntent.setType("image/*");

           //set photo
           shareCaptionIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
           shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));

           context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareCaptionIntent, "Share image using"));
        }
```

But until now without any success. Is there a way to share a content redirecting to the facebook browser page?

Comment: i think browser would not get extra data.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same trouble and I can say that that there is some trouble in `SharePhotoContent` API of facebook. You can share the image using `ShareLinkContent`.

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setImageUrl("Your url")
                .build();
shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```